# how do I replace the screw on my faucet handle?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, repair, shower, bathroom-fixtures

How do I get the screw out to replace with a new [faucet handle](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B004DQW8VG). Ideally, I'd have also liked to update the style of the handle, but I don't know if it is even possible without replacing the entire mechanism.

[image: Broken screw head]

Comment: There are ways of removing broken screws, screw extractors. drilling and retapping, grinding a slot in the the end.  Most might be a PITA to do.  Replacing the whole thing might just be easier to do, hate to say that for a simple screw.

Answer (score 0):

The valve looks similar to that in the diagram on [this page](https://www.plbg.com/forum/read.php?1,642049,642049). Notice that the dome-shaped outer cover (4 in the diagram) unscrews from the part in the wall. There may be no need to unscrew the cover plate, though it does no harm to take it off.

1. *Shut the water supply* to the shower.
2. Using large pliers with rubber-covered jaws (or wrapping the dome with rubber or thick tape) to protect the surface finish, turn the dome counter-clockwise a turn or so. Do not use excessive force.
3. Unscrew the dome by hand.
4. Inside parts are replaced as a single cartridge. For example, looking up [single handle shower cartridge](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=single+handle+shower+cartridge) shows *many* types, many in the US$20 range. Get one appropriate for *your* valve. These include the handle stem, broken in your photo.
5. Reassemble, and have someone *else* turn on the supply, so you can yell to them, "*Shut it off!*" should there be an issue. ;-)

Answer (score -1):

It looks like it was already severely tortured by someone.

It is not a screw, it is a part of the valve.

Either call a plumber or DIY it.

Remove the big outer cover held by one or two large screws.

That will expose the valve.

Turn water off and proceed disassembling the valve, or post pictures from what you see, so we can help with it.

If money is the issue, use caliper and measure the rood. Now go shopping for something that fits over it.

Comment: Once it's removed from the wall, take it to a _plumbing supply store_ (not a big-box plumbing aisle). Odds are good that the guy at the counter will recognize it and that they'll have one or more options in stock.